# JSON-like object in Python

Tags: python, json, object

I'm working with quite a bit of data in Python.  I'm currently using a lot of different arrays but I would like to use something similar to JSON format to make it easier.

something like:

```
metrics {
  .metric_name {
    .period {
      A: 10
      B: 20
    }
  }
}
```

so that I could call metrics.metric_name.A or whatever instead of using a lot of different multi-dim arrays.

Does anything like this exist in Python?  Can I use dictionaries inside of dictionaries?

Comment: why cant you use json instead of json like format ?

Comment: Yes. You can use unbounded nesting of dicts and lists, and the json module will eat it all up.

Answer (score 5):

```
metrics = {
  "metric_name" : {
    "period" : {
      "A": 10,
      "B": 20,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: and usage example: `print(metrics["metric_name"]["period"]["A"])` will print `10`

Comment: The sass in this answer was unwarranted.

Comment: @MattSidor Yes it is. Trying out things in Python is dead easy (with a simple script or the interactive shell), and one can get the answser to "Can I use dictionaries inside of dictionaries?" by oneself in less than 2 minutes. Posting the question here takes _much_ more time. If  the OP had made the effort to try it out and posted "I tried this it seems to work but I wonder is there's any pitfall or a better solution" I would certainly not have been ironic at all.

Comment: All valid points, but I don't think there's ever any justification for being so rude and condescending to someone. We should all strive to be welcoming and supportive to new developers. There was a way for you to get your point across without being so rude.

Comment: Well post a more welcoming and supportive answer then.